# Perfect power of two between two numbers

Tags: algorithm

How can I find perfect power of two between two numbers?
Sample input: 0 and 10
Output: 2, 4, 8

Comment: Why isn't 1 in your expected output?

Comment: ya we can add 1 also, that;s not a problem

Comment: no this is not a homework problem

Comment: @Nick Could you please throw some light on your approach

Comment: @Ajay, you can find how many times `2` divides a number with the log, base 2. round(lg(B) - lg(A)) is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the interesting part is "How do I get the greatest power of 2 that is less than or equal to my upper bound" and the same for the lowest power of 2 that is greater or equal to the lower bound.

And well, that's easily done without loops. For unsigned 32bit numbers:

```
floor(x):   ; floor power of 2
    x = x | (x >> 1)
    x = x | (x >> 2)
    x = x | (x >> 4)
    x = x | (x >> 8)
    x = x | (x >> 16)
    return x - (x >> 1)

ceil(x):   ; ceiling power of 2
    x = x - 1
    x = x | (x >> 1)
    x = x | (x >> 2)
    x = x | (x >> 4)
    x = x | (x >> 8)
    x = x | (x >> 16)
    return x + 1
```

You won't get around the loop for outputting the numbers though, but oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Find the highest bit set to 1 in first number, say it is at position x counting from lowest bit. Then find the highest bit set to 1 in the second number, say it is at position y. The numbers 2<sup>x+1</sup>, 2<sup>x+2</sup>..., 2<sup>y</sup> are the numbers you're looking for

Comment: can we do this without a while loop

Comment: @Ajay, if you have such a requirement, please update your question.

Comment: @Ajay: well, no, you will need a loop to find the highest bit set

Comment: Note that for the special case 0, there's no highest bit set to 1, so handle this accordingly.

Comment: @Ajay: Thank doesn't make sense! If you are going to print multiple numbers then it IS already a loop. Adding another one doesn't change the complexity. The complexity will be O(n) and no less anyway, . Yes, you can, of course do it on the fly, but it doesn't change anything..

Comment: @Ajay Are you attempting to use Stack Overflow to cheat on interview questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the binary representations of the numbers and output all the numbers between where only one bit is set:

```
0  = 00000000
10 = 00001010

=>

     00000001 (1)
     00000010 (2)
     00000100 (4)
     00001000 (8)
```

So your problem is reduced to finding the first power of two larger than the minimum and then shifting left while you're smaller than the maximum. Alternatively, unset all the set bits in the maximum value except the highest one and then shift right while you're larger than the minimum.

Comment: ya this i already know how can find these numbers which has bits set to one . for this i have to perform a looping, i there any way to perform this task without a loop

Comment: @Ajay: As your output always will be multiple numbers, you'll always have to use loops or at least something similar to looping (f.e. a recursive approach would be possible, but this wouldn't make much sense).

Answer (score 0):

How many times can you bit-shift before getting to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. Let's say `n1 = start_of_range`, `n2 = end_of_range.`
2. Find out how many bits are needed to represent `n1`. Call it `b`.
3. Now `2**b` will be the next power of two after `n1`.
4. It should be easy to calculate all the power of twos till `n2` from this.

Sample python code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def get_bits(n):
    b = 0
    while n:
        n = n / 2
        b += 1
    return b

def get_power_of_two_in_range(n1, n2):
    b = get_bits(n1)
    x = 2**b
    res = []
    while x < n2:
        res.append(x)
        x = x * 2
    return res

def main():
    print get_power_of_two_in_range(0, 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int first=0; //**first number which is a complete power of 2 in the range!**
 for(i=low;i<high;i++){
  if(2i==(i^(i-1)+1)){
   first=i;
   break;
  }
 }

while(first!=0){
 print first;
 first*=2;
 if(first>high){
  break;
}
}
```